# Search a bunch of gps files in a folder for final distance, output list of distances

Tags: grep, find, tail, exec

I have a bunch of .tcx files (essentially a GPS device outputted XML file) in a folder.  They follow the naming convention DATE_LOCATION_SPORT.tcx.  Each file has a bunch of track-point nodes noting key GPS data as recorded each second, within which there is a child distance-so-far node called "DistanceMeters". I want to grep through each file, and find the last "DistanceMeters" node, and then output that list of distances. Here's a snippet from a file.  (I am using OS X Sierra terminal)

```
…
<Trackpoint>
 <Time>2017-04-09T08:15:29.000Z</Time>
 <Position>
   <LatitudeDegrees>0.123456</LatitudeDegrees>
   <LongitudeDegrees>-0.654321</LongitudeDegrees>
  </Position>
  <AltitudeMeters>24.363636363636363</AltitudeMeters>
  <DistanceMeters>1382.3235298511217</DistanceMeters>
  <HeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
    <Value>130</Value>
  </HeartRateBpm>
</Trackpoint>
…
```

I started off by trying to do this with just one file (note, some of the filenames have spaces in, not sure if this is tripping me up);

```
grep '<DistanceMeters>.*<\/DistanceMeters>' '2017-03-23_Somewhere_Running.tcx' | tail -1 | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'
```

Which very nicely gets the last "DistanceMeters" node, and then uses grep to pull out the numerical distance rather than the whole line of xml.

```
find . -iname '2017*_Running.tcx'
```

The above gives me a list of all the files I am interested in for this year.

But when I try to combine the commands, it all falls apart.  I either get an error about not ending in a "\;" or, I get an answer, but only the last distance value for the last file in the file list, rather than a distance for each.

So this gives me the final distance of the last file in the list;

```
find . -iname '*_Running.tcx' -print0 | xargs -0 grep '<DistanceMeters>.*<\/DistanceMeters>' | tail -1 | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'
```

As does this;

```
find . -iname '*_Running.tcx' -exec grep '<DistanceMeters>.*<\/DistanceMeters>' {} \; | tail -1 | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'
```

I've tried various combinations, but I am not sure how to combine them the way I need.  I thought maybe putting the "\;" at the end would do it, but this doesn't work - complains about not ending in ";" or "+".

```
find . -iname '*_Running.tcx' -exec grep '<DistanceMeters>.*<\/DistanceMeters>' {} | tail -1 | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+' \;
```

yields

```
grep: ;: No such file or directory
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading this far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with quoting... I don't know if there's a way to quote this correctly so that the 'exec' option to find(1) will accept a pipeline of commands.

Here's one way to get around that problem:

```
$ for rfile in $(find . -iname '2017*_Running.tcx'); do grep '<DistanceMeters>.*<\/DistanceMeters>' $rfile | tail -1 | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'; done
```

Comment: `find -exec` can indeed only receive one command, and that command can't directly involve shell constructs like pipes... unless that command is a shell. `find . iname '2017*_Running.tcx' -exec sh -c 'for f; do grep '<DistanceMeters>.*</DistanceMeters>’ "$f" | tail -n 1 | grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'; done' _ +` (notice also how `/` doesn't need a backslash, and the `grep -E` at the end, which allows for simplifying the regex) though I would use an XML parser for this, or at least refactor this into an Awk script.

Comment: And `for file in $(find)` cannot work correctly in the general case; if the output from `find` contains whitespace or other shell metacharacters in the filenames, the shell won't parse them correctly when initializing the `for` loop. This is one of those pesky corner cases which is hard to solve completely correctly in shell scripts.